# Incoherence and the bandwidth of a source

Tags: coherence

It is generally accepted in the literature that the emission bandwidth $\Delta\nu$ of a light source is inversely proportional to its coherence time $\tau_\mathrm{coh}$, i.e.:
$$
\Delta\nu \propto 1/\tau_\mathrm{coh}.
$$
Given that an incoherent light source ($\tau_\mathrm{coh} \rightarrow 0$) such as an incandescent lamp or a fluorophore should have an infinite emission bandwidth, which is not generally true because such light sources while having a large bandwidth of tens or even hundreds of nanometers, however their bandwidth is finite. Where is the error in this reasoning? Maybe it is the wrong assumption that $\tau_\mathrm{coh} \rightarrow 0$ for such light sources?

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot never have a source that has $\tau_\mathrm{coh}=0$ because the source would not have any radiative modes.
2. Coherence is best described by correlation functions, and then use the Weiner-Khitchine theorem to find the spectrum.

Also, you need to differential between spatial and temporal coherence.  In your question, you've implicitly assumed temporal coherence.

Some examples:

1. Sunlight has a large spectrum, yet I can (as Thomas Young once did) form fringes using a double slit experiment.
2. Star light, despite being made up of billions and billions of independent radiators, will have their light become more coherent as it propagates towards the earth.  This is why stars twinkle when it interacts with the atmosphere.  The Zernkike-Van Cittert theorem explains this.
3. Photon bunching, and anti-bunching, are phenomena not captured by your simple expression.

To address your question more directly, it isn't sufficient to specify the bandwidth to understand a source's coherence.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a relationship between the coherence time and the bandwidth, but it is only in the form of an inequality: a very narrow bandwidth does imply a long coherence time, i.e. $\tau_\mathrm{coh} \gtrsim 1/\Delta\nu$, but that is all you can say.

In particular, it is indeed incorrect to say that "incoherent" light sources have $\tau_\mathrm{coh}=0$. The idea of a "fully incoherent" light source is a useful idealization and approximation in some settings, but there is no such thing in the real world $-$ every light source has a finite coherence time, and the only question is whether that coherence time (or the corresponding coherence length) is relevant to the setting under consideration or whether it is much shorter than any other relevant length and time scale involved.

The examples you give are essentially thermal sources, and for these the coherence length $\ell_\mathrm{coh}$ is inversely proportional to the temperature $T$ [cf. [Eur. J. Phys. 19 245 (1998)](http://doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/19/3/006)], with the scale set by the relation
$$
\ell_\mathrm{coh} T 
\simeq
3.6 \:\rm mm\:K
.
$$